How to make my blazor webassembly project run from file folder (by double clicking to open it)
I've created a blazor webassembly project, it can run from VS, but after I published it to my local folder, for the index.html, can I run it by double clicking it?
Do I have to use a web server?
Can I embed everything (like .css .js .wasm) into the .html file?
I have an error like this:



Do I have to use a web server?

Yes
An example:
install dotnet-serve
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-serve

start the server
dotnet serve -o -S

result:

